# Merging a pandas DataFrame with a Series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, series

I have this df:

```
             cnpj
0  33062217000185
1  82645144000160
```

I run a function that creates two different Series:

```
for i in df.cnpj:
    s=peer_comparison(i)
    df=df.merge(peers.to_frame().T, how='left', on='cnpj')
```

In the first round of the for sentence, the output series goes like this:

```
s (first round):

A                                  N/A
B                                  N/A
C                                  N/A
cnpj                    33062217000185
```

The merged dataframe looks like this:

```
             cnpj   A       B     C
0  33062217000185   N/A   N/A   N/A 
1  82645144000160   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

When it goes to the second round of merging, the series look like this:

```
s (second round):

A                                  N/A
B                                  N/A
C                                  N/A
cnpj                    82645144000160
```

But the merging gets all messy, like this:

```
             cnpj   A_x   B_x  C_x  A_y  B_y  C_y
0  33062217000185   N/A   N/A  N/A  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  82645144000160   NaN   NaN  NaN  N/A  N/A  N/A
```

If I try to change the merging using `df.merge(s.to_frame().T.astype({'cnpj' : 'int'}), how='left',on='cnpj').fillna('')` I get the following error:

```
ValueError: entry not a 2- or 3- tuple
```

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

**Setup**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'cnpj': [33062217000185, 82645144000160]})
print(df)
             cnpj
0  33062217000185
1  82645144000160

s = pd.Series(['N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A', 33062217000185], index=['A', 'B', 'C', 'cnpj'])
print(s)
A                  N/A
B                  N/A
C                  N/A
cnpj    33062217000185
dtype: object
```

---

Use `df.merge`, converting `s` to a dataframe and transposing in the process.

```
df.merge(s.to_frame().T\
      .astype({'cnpj' : 'int'}), how='left').fillna('')
             cnpj    A    B    C
0  33062217000185  N/A  N/A  N/A
1  82645144000160
```

Comment: I'm using it inside a for sentence. For the first one it structures perfectly, but change the name of the series columns adding a "_x" (A_x, B_x, etc) to it. When it goes to the second one, it creates new columns adding a "_y" on it, structuring properly the second row but leaving the first row with NaNs (and I needed it to be N/As)

Comment: @abutremutante Yeah, I hope you saw my recent edit, I explicitly recreated the data so it would work exactly as expected in your question.

Comment: @abutremutante If the problem still persists, I can't say for sure what the problem is unless you show me some sample data that reproduces your problem?

Comment: Another problem came out actually: ValueError: entry not a 2- or 3- tuple. Should I edit the question adding the for sentence? The data inside the cells are actually really N/As.

Comment: @abutremutante Maybe. And some code lines that helps me _reproduce_ your data would also help.

Comment: @COLDSPEED I edited the question. Could you have a look?

Comment: @abutremutante Oh I see now. You’re merging at each iteration? Don’t do that. Instead, you should accumulate your series (preferably into a data frame) and then merge only once.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155793/discussion-between-abutremutante-and-cs).

Comment: @abutremutante Alright, were you able to figure something out?

Comment: Yes, I was just writing it. Worked out using concatenate and forgeting about df.     peers=peer_comparison(df.cnpj[0])
    for i in df.cnpj[1:]:
        peers2=peer_comparison(i,base_year)
        peers=pd.concat([peers,peers2],axis=1)

    df=peers.T. If you'd like to edit your answer with that be my guest, thanks a lot for your constant help.

Answer (score 0):

Getting some of @COLDSPEED tips and using concat instead of merge or join it finally worked.

```
peers=peer_comparison(df.cnpj[0])
for i in df.cnpj[1:]:
    peers2=peer_comparison(i,base_year)
    peers=pd.concat([peers,peers2],axis=1)

df=peers.T
```